# localstorage how to save a div

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I need to save a div with localstorage. When i press a button the div becomes visible but when i close the browser and open it again the div needs to be visible.

This is my code so far:

```
<script>
function openDiv() {
    var film = document.getElementById("bookingDiv");
    if(film.style.display == "none"){
        film.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function save() {
    openDiv()
    var saveDiv = document.getElementById("bookingDiv")
    if(saveDiv.style.display == "block"){

    localstorage.setItem("text", saveDiv)

    }

}

function load() {
    var loadDiv = localstorage.getItem("text")
    if(loadDiv){

        document.getElementById("bookingDiv") = loadDiv

    }

}   

</script>

<body onload="load()">


<input type="button" id="testButton" value="Save" onclick="save()" />
<div style="display:none" id="bookingDiv" type="text">
hello
</div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only store strings using the `localStorage`. So you have to store the state of this element instead of the element itself.

```
function save() {
    openDiv();
    var saveDiv = document.getElementById("bookingDiv");
    if (saveDiv.style.display == "block") {

        localStorage.setItem("isTextVisible", true);

    }

}

function load() {
    var isTextVisible = localStorage.getItem("isTextVisible");
    if (isTextVisible == "true") {

        openDiv();

    }

}
```

note: do not forget the semicolon after each statement as it might lead to wrong behavior!